# Forecasting weekly count

Tags: python, machine-learning, forecasting

I have a weekly sales data as follows:

```
date           Total_sales
2016-01-04     10
2016-01-05     72
2016-01-06     64
2016-01-07     94
2016-01-08     94
2016-01-09    158
2016-01-10     65
2016-01-11     70
2016-01-12    115
2016-01-13    126
2016-01-14    140
2016-01-15    179
2016-01-16    181
2016-01-17    123
2016-01-18     96
2016-01-19    111
2016-01-20    199
2016-01-21    184
2016-01-22    215
2016-01-23    257
2016-01-24    151
2016-01-25    114
2016-01-26    209
2016-01-27    190
2016-01-28    208
2016-01-29    218
2016-01-30    243
2016-01-31    150
2016-02-01    147
2016-02-02    173
2016-02-03    168
2016-02-04    169
2016-02-05    142
2016-02-06    188
2016-02-07    130
2016-02-08     82
2016-02-09    102
2016-02-10     89
2016-02-11     93
2016-02-12     97
2016-02-13     75
2016-02-14     39
2016-02-15     54
2016-02-16     39
2016-02-17     44
2016-02-18     44
2016-02-19     38
2016-02-20     53
2016-02-21     31
2016-02-22     24
2016-02-23     27
2016-02-24     17
2016-02-25     10
2016-02-26      8
2016-02-27     12
2016-02-28      5
2016-02-29      1
```

The original data has each row for a transaction with the date variable and other attribute of a transaction. I have grouped it by date and taken a count of date here

Now, If I again group it by week, as below:

```
df.groupby([df.transaction_date.dt.week])['transaction_date'].count()
```

the data looks like this:

```
1.0     557
2.0     934
3.0    1213
4.0    1332
5.0    1117
6.0     577
7.0     303
8.0     103
9.0       1
```

Where 1.0 etc is the week no.

Now I want to forecast weekly sales no from this data.

Any suggestion if I should just use a basic linear regression on this data (problem is its just a univariate data (count by week) so am not sure there is a linear regression can be attempted here as there is no IV here).

So any suggestion how to approach this on this small data points for forecasting?

Comment: Since your data is dependent on time, you should probably try a time series model like ARIMA, have you tried anything so far though?

Comment: Well I was thinking of trying LSTM, since that's what I know currently which can be used on a sequence data. I am not very familiar with ARIMA especially how to do it in Python

Comment: but my data is very small (weekly data points are just 9) LSTM won't work for this I guess. Will ARIMA work with just 9 points?

Comment: if you have such a small dataset I don't think using LSTM is any good option.

Comment: yeah. Any resources for quick ARIMA iimplemention in Python? Thanks

Comment: Yes, let me add them as answer, would that be OK?

Comment: sure. Thanks. If u have code for that to add it can be helpful to reference that.

Comment: added an answer, hope that helps. For the implementation, I've linked few articles. Thanks

Comment: Also check the Prophet package (available in both R and python)

Answer (score 0):

Since your time variant data is small, you should probably go for a statistical model like, in your case a time series model.  ARIMA or autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) models are used to find the best fit of a time-series model to past values of a time series. There will be three step of the forecast, which are given below:

1. Model identification and model selection: making sure that the variables are stationary, identifying seasonality in the dependent series (seasonally differencing it if necessary), and using plots of the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions of the dependent time series to decide which (if any) autoregressive or moving average component should be used in the model.
2. Parameter estimation using computation algorithms to arrive at coefficients that best fit the selected ARIMA model. The most common methods use maximum likelihood estimation or non-linear least-squares estimation.
3. Model checking by testing whether the estimated model conforms to the specifications of a stationary univariate process. In particular, the residuals should be independent of each other and constant in mean and variance over time. (Plotting the mean and variance of residuals over time and performing a Ljung–Box test or plotting autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation of the residuals are helpful to identify misspecification.) If the estimation is inadequate, we have to return to step one and attempt to build a better model.

Referenced to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average

Regarding its python implementation, there is a `[statmodels][1]` package in python, which you can utilize. I would suggest you two resources which give you the full explanation of its implementation in python.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/
https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

Apart from this method, you may want to try Random Forest regression and XGBOOST, but my suggestion for the first go would be `ARIMA` since your data is time dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a graph, you'll see you are at the end of a wave, so and ARIMA may not be the solution (as it can only fit polynomial models).

You may first use cumulative data, in order to wipe out the fluctuation, then fit a logistic curve (not to be confused with the chaotic logistic map nor the logistic logit).

You then discover your sale is filling a market niche of 6745 units, out of which a total of 6137 have already be sold. It remains 608 unit to be sold. They will follow a decreasing pattern: 60 on week 9, 27 on week 10, 12 on week 11, 5 on week 12,... The remaining will depend more on a strategic decision to continue or not to sell the product than of filling the market niche.

[image]